# Loading CSV to elasticsearch index with mapping using Python API

Tags: python, csv, elasticsearch, bulk

Using the elasticsearch Python API I want to create an elasticsearch index with a mapping so that when I upload a CSV file the documents are uploaded according to this mapping.

```
import argparse, elasticsearch, json
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk
import csv
```

I have this (I removed some fields so the mapping doesn't look that long):

```
mapping = 
'''{
"mappings": {
  "type": {
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "@version": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "authEndStopCode": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "expandedTripNumber": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "operator": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "path": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "startStopName": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "userStartStopCode": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
}'''
```

I'm creating the index this way:

```
es.indices.create(index=INDEX_NAME, ignore=400, body=mapping)
```

This is what I do to upload the data:

```
with open(args.file, "r", encoding="latin-1") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    bulk(es, reader, index=INDEX_NAME, doc_type=TYPE)
```

Where `INDEX_NAME` and `TYPE` are strings I already defined.

The CSV file is just data (it should be one document per line), doesn't have headers, but elasticsearch seems like it's trying to use the first line as the headers. I don't want this, I want to use the mapping I already added to the index.

Hope someone can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't bulk. `csv.DictReader` always reads the first line from the file to get the headers for subsequent rows. So if you're going to use `DictReader`, the file needs a header.

Comment: it's not only a problem of csv.DictReader but all the dictionaries and json objects that needs keys and values. If you use these structures, you have to specify the keys of the values

Comment: so how do you fix it? Can you specify correct code?

Comment: @Enthusiast, you can add a header to the file using
    
`from subprocess import call`
`call ["sed", "-i", '1i ' + "header", path/to/file]`
where "header" is the line you want to add

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of [moshe/elasticsearch_loader](https://github.com/Moshe/elasticsearch_loader)
I wrote ESL for this exact problem.
You can download it with pip:

```
pip install elasticsearch-loader
```

And then you will be able to load csv files into elasticsearch while supplying your custom mapping by issuing:

```
elasticsearch_loader  --index-settings-file mappings.json \
     --index incidents --type incident csv file1.csv
```